# What's wrong with this array method(Java)? How to get rid of '\n' in a better way?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm creating a table for teams and have this method for registering points for teams:

```
public void registerPointsForTeam(String[] t, int[] p) {

    System.out.print("Team: ");

    String choiceTeam = scanner.nextLine(); 
    String garbage = scanner.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Points: ");
    int choicePoints = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if (choiceTeam.equalsIgnoreCase(t[i])) {
            p[i] = p[i] + choicePoints;     
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I have String garbage since nextLine(), as I understand it, adds and extra '\n'.

Cheers/C

Comment: Is this Java? Please add a tag indicating the programming language.

Comment: Why not use `scanner.next()`?

Comment: You are wrong about `nextLine()` adding an extra `\n`.  I think you're confusing this with what happens after `nextInt()`.  After `nextInt()`, there will be an `\n` left in the input stream, and you have to call `nextLine()` to get rid of it.  So you want your "garbage" read to be **after** `nextInt()`, not before.  Also, you can just say `scanner.nextLine()`; you don't have to declare a garbage variable to throw away the result.